# "DefaultWinRMCertificateThumbprint" is empty in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I have provisioned the new virtual machine(VM) using VHD by performing following actions,

- We copied a VHD file of a VM from one storage account to another
- created a VM using VHD files.

After creating the VM, we are able to do RDP (Remote Desktop) into the machine successfully, however not able to perform the Remote Powershell functionality. 
To be more precise not able to execute commands remotely using Invoke-Command in powershell.

It seems that RDP Thumbprint(DefaultWinRMCertificateThumbprint) is empty for newly created virtual machine.

How we can install or configure certificates or thumbprints to enable remote execution of commands?

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.